# How do I display a list of objects based on a specific property in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, angularjs-filter

I have a one to many model of related collections in mongodb where a doc in the child collection includes the id of a doc in the parent collection. I'm trying to display all children when viewing the parent.

When viewing the parent, I have an ng-repeat that displays the entire child collection. I'm struggling with filtering the child collection so that it only displays results that include the parent id.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div>{{parent.name}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="child in children | filter: {id: {{parent.id}}}">
    {{child.name}}
</div>
```

Here's my js:

```
app.controller("parentCtrl", function($scope, $location, $routeParams, $http) {  
    //Get parent 
    $scope.children = [];
    $http.get('/children').success(function(children) {
        $scope.loaded = true;
        $scope.children = children;
    });
});
```

The code successfully gets the parent and loads all docs in the child collection. Can I use a filter in my ng-repeat to pull just the children? If not, is there a best practice to get docs from a related collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.id` shouldn't be wrap with interpolation(`{{}}`) as it needs an expression that evaluates against scope.

```
ng-repeat="child in children | filter: {id: parent.id }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<div>{{parent.name}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="(k, child) in children | filter: {id: parent.id}"
    {{child.name}}
</div>
```